# Ninject nested dependencies and inheritance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inheritance, dependency-injection, ninject

**Problem:**

I want to inject a particular subclass, when the call hierarchy contains a particular subclassed MVC controller.

**Example:**

Note: The specific senario I'm dealing with is different, Areas and Currencies are just easy to reason with.

```
AreaController<TModel> : AreaController where TModel : AreaModel

UsaController : AreaController<UsaModel>
EuropeController : AreaController<EuropeModel>

class AreaController<TModel> : AreaController where TModel : AreaModel
{
    // Builds up the model using IModelBuilder.
    // ModelBuilder uses lots of builder components, one of them being ICurrencyBuilder
}

class UsaController
{
    public UsaController(IModelBuilder modelBuilder) : base (modelBuilder) {}
}

class EuropeController
{
    public EuropeController(IModelBuilder modelBuilder) : base (modelBuilder) {}
}

class ModelBuilder : IModelBuilder
{
    public ModelBuilder(ICurrencyBuilder currencyBuilder) {}
}

class CurrencyBuilder : ICurrencyBuilder
{
    public CurrencyBuilder() {}
}
```

For Europe, the currencyBuilder needs to be subclassed, as determining the currency is more involved there. Therefore I have:

```
class EuropeCurrencyBuilder : ICurrencyBuilder
{
    public CurrencyBuilder(IlocationService locationService) {}
}
```

So what I want, is when calling from a EuropeController, the ICurrencyBuilder chosen to be EuropeCurrencyBuilder.

**What I've tried:**

I first thought I could use:

```
kernel.Bind<ICurrencyBuilder>()
    .To<EuropeCurrencyBuilder>()
    .WhenInjectedInto<EuropeController>();
```

However it seems when Ninject talk about a Hierarchy, they're talking about the inheritance hierarchy, not the call hierarchy.

Which is leading me to think my best option is to do the following:

```
class EuropeModelBuilder : ModelBuilder {
    // No change in behaviour, just a class name
}

kernel.Bind<IModelBuilder>()
    .To<EuropeModelBuilder>()
    .WhenInjectedInto<EuropeController>();

kernel.Bind<ICurrencyBuilder>()
    .To<EuropeCurrencyBuilder>()
    .WhenInjectedInto<EuropeModelBuilder>();
```

Which works, but is it my best option?

Comment: Your solution requires the same decision to be made twice (two conditional bindings for europe). You should refactor so that the decision needs to be done once only.  Without seeing the specific code in play it is hard to give specific refactoring advice. I suspect that building up the entire object tree in one go might be the ideal solution. I'm not sure, but it might be that given the question with complete code this might be a better fit for the Code Review site.